# Stitch Together a Palindrome from Palindromic Substrings

Tags: code-golf, array, permutations, palindrome

Given a string `l`, find all palindromic substrings `p` of `l` (including duplicates and single character strings). Next, rearrange all sub-strings in `p` into a valid palindrome (there may be multiple correct answers). If it is not possible to rearrange `p` into a single palindrome, your program may have undefined behavior (error, stack-overflow, exiting, hanging/untimely murder of John Dvorak, etc...)

---

## Examples

### Valid Test Cases

```
l = anaa
p = ['a', 'n', 'a', 'a', 'aa', 'ana']
result = anaaaaana or aanaaanaa or aaananaaa

l = 1213235
p = ['1', '2', '1', '3', '2', '3', '5', '121', '323']
result = 1213235323121

l = racecar
p = ['r', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'cec', 'aceca', 'racecar']
result = racecarcecaacecracecar (there are others)

l = 11233
p = ['1', '11', '1', '2', '3', '33', '3']
result = 113323311 or 331121133

l = abbccdd
p = ['a', 'b', 'bb', 'b', 'c', 'cc', 'c', 'd', 'dd', 'd']
result = bbccddaddccbb or ccbbddaddbbcc or (etc...)

l = a
p = ['a']
result = a
```

### Invalid Test Cases (Not Possible)

```
l = 123456789
p = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
result = <not possible, behavior undefined>

l = hjjkl
p = ['h', 'j', 'jj', 'j', 'k', 'l']
result = <not possible, behavior undefined>

l = xjmjj
p = ['x', 'j', 'jmj', 'm', 'j', 'jj', 'j']
result = <not possible, behavior undefined>
```

---

## Rules

- If the input word is a palindrome itself, it will always be valid as input.
- Only one substring should be returned, which one you choose is arbitrary as long as it's valid.
- If the input has no viable output, your code may have undefined behavior.
- Inputs will only contain ASCII-Printable characters between `0x20-0x7E`.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count is the winner.

Comment: The first proposed result for `"abbccdd"` is wrong: the last two letters should be `"bb"`, not `"dd"`.

Comment: Can we return an array of substrings, rather than a single string?

Comment: Can I take a list of characters as input?

Comment: By hanging being acceptable behavior, do you mean hanging the person who gave it input?

Comment: @JohnDvorak clarified.

Comment: I ... refuse :P

Comment: @JohnDvorak :P. +1-byte penalty for users your program hangs other than John Dvorak.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
{s.↔}ᶠpc.↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7pY71HblNqH2xYUJINY//8rAWVTkxOLlP5HAQA)

Fails (i.e. prints `false.`) if not possible.

#### Explanation

```
{   }ᶠ         Find all…
 s.              …substrings of the input…
  .↔             …which are their own reverse
      p        Take a permutation of this list of palindromes
       c.      The output is the concatenation of this permutation
        .↔     The output is its own reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 140 bytes

```
s->p(map(''.join,permutations(p(v for k in n(s)for v in n(k[::-1])))))[0]
from itertools import*
n=scan$((+))
p=list..filter$(x->x==x[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEADvviKHQjZtlfYqxI9YDyGobNXdsInioX9PlXZuA8N49kxryqN95Vg2ARYXQOvqzUj30MuyJpeQKUKATQ0salJIiiCaU7afTG1dl8/OnLSPrhiEF4Wpl8Q8R4VLYEnXgmz0ji4AN2OKYGeMqaoGnI/wAnvZ7Nbu/1PW4nzvnWj1aVQQpCMdc9t9AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 193 bytes

*"Look Ma, no permutation built-in!"* (So yes ... it's long ...)

Returns an empty array if there's no solution.

```js
f=(s,a=[].concat(...[...s].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>s.slice(i,j+1)))).filter(P=s=>[...s].reverse().join``==s&&s),m=S=[])=>S=a.map((_,i)=>f(s,b=[...a],[...m,b.splice(i,1)]))>''?S:P(m.join``)||S
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(s,a=[].concat(...[...s].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>s.slice(i,j+1)))).filter(P=s=>[...s].reverse().join``==s&&s),m=S=[])=>S=a.map((_,i)=>f(s,b=[...a],[...m,b.splice(i,1)]))>''?S:P(m.join``)||S

console.log(f('anaa'))
console.log(f('1213235'))
console.log(f('hjjkl'))
console.log(f('a'))
```

#### How?

Let's split the code into smaller parts.

We define **P()**, a function that returns **s** if **s** is a palindrome, or **false** otherwise.

```js
P = s => [...s].reverse().join`` == s && s
```

We compute all substrings of the input string **s**. Using **P()**, we isolate the non-empty palindromes and store them in the array **a**.

```js
a = [].concat(...[...s].map((_, i, a) => a.map((_, j) => s.slice(i, j + 1)))).filter(P)
```

The main recursive function **f()** takes **a** as input and compute all its permutations. It updates **S** whenever the permutation itself is a palindrome (once joined), and eventually returns the final value of **S**.

```js
f = (                        // given:
  a,                         //   a[] = input array
  m = S = []                 //   m[] = current permutation of a[]
) =>                         //   and S initialized to []
  S = a.map((_, i) =>        // for each element at position i in a[]:
    f(                       //   do a recursive call with:
      b = [...a],            //     b[] = copy of a[] without the i-th element
      [...m, b.splice(i, 1)] //     the element extracted from a[] added to m[]
    )                        //   end of recursive call
  ) > '' ?                   // if a[] was not empty:
    S                        //   let S unchanged
  :                          // else:
    P(m.join``) || S         //   update S to m.join('') if it's a palindrome
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ŒḂÐf
ẆÇŒ!F€ÇḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7mg5PSON6uKvtcPvRSYpuj5rWHG5/uGPR////ow11FIDICEjGAgA)

Prints `0` in the invalid case.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
ŒʒÂQ}œJʒÂQ}¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6KRTkw43BdYenewFYRxa8v9/YlJiIgA)

-1 byte thanks to Magic Octopus Urn and Emigna.

Comment: `J` automatically factorizes so you don't need `€J` just `J`; also, you're supposed to return one of the palindromes, not all.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6KRTkw43BdYenewFYRyeeaT9///EvMREAA "05AB1E – Try It Online") is valid for the same byte-count.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Fixed, thanks !

Comment: `Ùć` could be `¤` (or a number of other options)

Comment: @Emigna not sure why I didn't see the `Ù` wasn't needed.

Comment: Enigma My bad, for an unknown reason I thought we were supposed to display all of the unique palindromes, hence the original Ù. Thanks for the tip, fixed !

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A7%C2%BB%C2%AC%E2%96%BA%C3%96%E2%88%9Ej%E2%88%9E%3A%C3%86%E2%95%98%CF%84%CE%B4&i=%22a%22%0A%0A%22anaa%22%0A%0A%221213235%22%0A%0A%22abbccdd%22%0A%0A%22racecar%22%0A%0A%2211233%22&a=1&m=1), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç»¬►Ö∞j∞:Æ╘τδ
```

[Run test cases](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A7%C2%BB%C2%AC%E2%96%BA%C3%96%E2%88%9Ej%E2%88%9E%3A%C3%86%E2%95%98%CF%84%CE%B4&i=%22a%22%0A%0A%22anaa%22%0A%0A%221213235%22%0A%0A%22abbccdd%22%0A%0A%22racecar%22%0A%0A%2211233%22&a=1&m=1) (It takes about 10 seconds on my current machine)

This is the corresponding ascii representation of the same program.

```
:e{cr=fw|Nc$cr=!
```

It's not quite *pure* brute-force, but it's just as small as the brute-force implementation I wrote.  That one crashed my browser after about 10 minutes.  Anyway, here's how it works.

```
:e                  Get all contiguous substrings
  {cr=f             Keep only those that are palindromes
       w            Run the rest of the program repeatedly while a truth value is produced.
        |N          Get the next permutation.
          c$        Copy and flatten the permutation.
            cr=!    Test if it's palindrome.  If not, repeat.
                    The last permutation produced will be implicitly printed.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>131</s> <s>123</s> 120 bytes

```ruby
->s{m=->t{t==t.reverse}
(1..z=s.size).flat_map{|l|(0..z-l).map{|i|s[i,l]}}.select(&m).permutation.map(&:join).detect &m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVL9bpswEP@fp7CQEoGUWAOara1E9iAIVYftqGbGibDptoY8e@azgdAhYd/vy@aw@6H5ez@V9/3RXLtyf7RXW5aW9uJD9EbcoiSj9LM01MhPkdKTAvvWweU6qjH55pS9SqnHcjSV3Kn6dqNGKMFssu1SehF9N1iw8qzRlmxf27PUKeXCOgvZdrd7FRFSxaAB4h3xT0Du0UjF4FHQY18hjut655NZnhV5cfDhBbnXVRgI1SHwS6gHJhj0U2hCOC6FF2cFB6xWCjykhxA@8YFXcVRWxlV8UuBrBsdHj1leFNPvQVS4Xoos9OfmHJnFDE3DGOdTbwEA54w1DQaaBmtANhAoeAdaA4E1BCMSQYJgDATW80bLxvMBhjNcnVDxdPj@4/nF6ZWWaubf2/aXmrta8X/arm2/8FFNBbB3ws9klPoy2B35ACX5G2jz293T0eV6YQZlSUlOlbfUjnOTIfHmxZDySDb5kyHJxqQx2ZBqWiakqNTm4i7kf8s6mqmBi59JsKV1JDSP7v8A)

A lambda accepting a string and returning a string. Returns `nil` when no solution exists.

-5 bytes: Replace `select{|t|l[t]}` with `select(&l)`

-3 bytes: Replace `map{..}.flatten` with `flat_map{...}`

-1 bytes: Loop over substring length and substring start, instead of over substring start and substring end

-2 bytes: Declare `z` at first use instead of beforehand

```ruby
->s{
  l=->t{t==t.reverse}        # Lambda to test for palindromes
  (1..z=s.size).flat_map{|l| # For each substring length
    (0..z-l).map{|i|         # For each substring start index
      s[i,l]                 # Take the substring
    }
  }                          # flat_map flattens the list of lists of substrings
  .select(&l)                # Filter to include only palindromic substrings
  .permutation               # Take all orderings of substrings
  .map(&:join)               # Flatten each substring ordering into a string
  .detect &l                 # Find the first palindrome
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 167 bytes

```python
lambda a:g(sum(k,[])for k in permutations(g(a[i:j+1]for i in range(len(a))for j in range(i,len(a)))))[0]
g=lambda k:[e for e in k if e==e[::-1]]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU1LDsIgFNz3FG8JWhOrOxJOgiwwPvC15RNKF54ewTRxMpnFfDLpU94x3KuVj7oa/3wZMMKxbfdsGZXmNmZYgAIkzH4vplAMG3PMKBLzedI9p55nExyyFQMz/Lea/y6Nh9@grnpw8rhahELoZezl9mMBpUQlxGXSerA5eqCCucS4bkA@xVxONWUKhVmmphEab0015/UL)

-2 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: You can use `a[i:j+1]` if you then use `for j in range(i,len(a))` instead, for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
h_I#sM.p_I#.:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyPeU7nYV68ASOlZ/f8fbaijAERGQDIWAA)

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: Lol I was so sure nobody else uses Pyth that I submitted my own  separate answer (now deleted) prior to seeing yours. You can use `h_I#sM.p_I#.:` or `e_IDsM.p_I#.:` for 13 bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh haha :P yeah I hardly ever use Pyth, don't know why I decided to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 19 bytes

Hampered by Japt not (yet) being able to get *all* substrings of a string (and partly by my current levels of exhaustion!).

Outputs `undefined` if there's no solution.

```
Êõ@ãX fêQÃc á m¬æêQ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=yvVA41ggZupRw2Mg4SBtrObqUQ==&input=ImFuYWEi)

---

### Explanation

```
                        :Implicit input of string U
Ê                       :Length of U
 õ                      :Range [1,Ê]
  @      Ã              :Pass each X through a function
   ãX                   :  Substrings of U of length X
      f                 :  Filter
       êQ               :    Is it a palindrome?
          c             :Flatten
            á           :Permutations
              m         :Map
               ¬        :  Join to a string
                æêQ     :Get first element that is a palindrome
```

Comment: Is your question about a list of substring simply to remove `¬` from your answer :P?

Comment: Thought I could remove `m¬` but then I would have needed `æ_¬êQ` so it wouldn't have saved any bytes anyway!

Comment: Hahaha, I'll ensure to be wary of your byte-saving ways from now on ;). I tried removing it myself to check, but realized japt commands don't work like I think they work lol.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
ḟS=↔mΣPfS=↔Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@cG2j9qm5J5bHJAGZgX@//9fqSgxOTU5sUgJAA)

### Explanation

```
ḟS=↔mΣPfS=↔Q  Implicit input, a string.
           Q  List of substrings.
       f      Keep those
        S=↔   that are palindromic (equal to their reversal).
      P       Permutations of this list.
    mΣ        Flatten each.
ḟ             Find an element
 S=↔          that is palindromic.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 53 bytes

```
[:{:@(#~b"1)@(i.@!@#;@A.])@(#~(0<#*b=.]-:|.)&>)@,<\\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o62qrRw0lOuSlAw1HTQy9RwUHZStHRz1YjVBohoGNspaSbZ6sbpWNXqaanaaDjo2MTF6/zW5FLhSkzPyFdIU1BPzEhPV4byixOTU5MQihEBGVlZ2DoJraGhkbKzO9R8A)